# Getting error in converting Json response to java object while writing test cases

Tags: java, json, gson

I am working with an api and using Gson to convert Json response into java object. The code is working fine and I am getting the required results, but when I am writing test cases I am getting a `ClassCastException`.

**GET Call**:

```
String jsonResponse = getData(parameter1,parameter2);//api call
if(!StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(jsonResponse, "null"))
{`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);`
Gson gson = new Gson();
somejavaObject = gson.fromJson((String) jsonObject.get("data"),
               javaObject.class);
}
```

**POST call**:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String objectString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("data", objectString);
request.put("otherData", someValue);
//then POST call
```

**Test case for GET call**:

```
String json = "{\"data\": {\"value1\": {\"v1\": 123, \"v2\": 456}, \"list\": [{\"l1\": 123, \"l2\" :456}]}}";

PowerMockito.doReturn(json).when(spy,"getData",parameters);
```

The above code is working for the api but failing the test case at the above line and throwing me error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem was that I casted to a wrong type.

```
somejavaObject = gson.fromJson((String) jsonObject.get("data"), javaObject.class);
```

I changed the line above to

```
somejavaObject = gson.fromJson( jsonObject.get("data").toString(), javaObject.class);
```

and it works now.

Comment: Very good! Whenever the compiler suggests you need to cast to a `String`, or it seems like you should cast to a `String`, **never cast to a String**. Always use a `toString()` or `String.valueOf(Object)`.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you try this solution**

```
String json = "{\"data\": {\"value1\": {\"v1\": 123, \"v2\": 456}, \"list\": [{\"l1\": 123, \"l2\" :456}]}}";
         //convert string format  to JSON format
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        PowerMockito.doReturn(gson.toJson(json)).when(spy,"getData",parameters)
```

**Updated Answer**

> It will give me json, starting with " " "(a double quote). Giving me
>   error :A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1

Try to use this

```
String json = "{\"data\": {\"value1\": {\"v1\": 123, \"v2\": 456}, \"list\": [{\"l1\": 123, \"l2\" :456}]}}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       PowerMockito.doReturn(jsonObject).when(spy,"getData",parameters);
```

Comment: No, it didn't work. it will give me json, starting with " " "(a double quote). Giving me error :A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1.